# Is a Feynman vertex valid only if all its rotations are?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

Consider a toy universe with only the following particles/fields:

1. A lepton $\psi$, with antiparticle $\bar \psi$.
2. A vector boson $A$ (self-conjugate), that does not interact with itself.

Based only on spin, lepton number, and the above, it seems like we should be able to have a 4-point vertex $\psi + \bar \psi \to A + A$. However, it seems like the rotated diagram $A + A \to \psi + \bar \psi$ should be forbidden, because $A$ does not self-interact (unless I am misunderstanding what that means). Does that mean that the first vertex is forbidden too, or can a Feynman vertex be valid even if its rotated version is not? How about the other rotations, like $\psi + A \to \psi + A$?

I guess my main source of confusion is that I have become accustomed to QED, where the allowed vertices can be rotated arbitrarily. But I am unsure if this is a general fact or theory specific.

---

The comments have lead me to think that the main issue is the interpretation of the statement that $A$ "does not interact with itself". I can think of two different interpretations:

1. There are no terms in the Lagrangian with *only* two $A$:s. So no mass term $\sim m_A A_\mu A^\mu$.
2. There are no terms in the Lagrangian with two $A$:s, even along with other fields. (I don't know any examples of such terms from other theories anyway, but maybe they are possible in principle?)

As an aside, since both interpretations forbid a mass term, that must imply that $A$ is massless, right? (Assuming there is nothing like the Higgs mechanism, in this toy universe, that can grant mass to bosons.)

Comment: what, exactly, does "*does not interact with itself*" mean? this is the key to your question, so try to think about it and see if you can explain what this means (ideally in equations, not just words!).

Comment: I think you may want to review how Feynman rules originate from Lagrangians. In other words, why don’t you try to write down the interaction term that generates your 4-vertex.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Well, I suppose I am not entirely sure. It could be that it just means that there is no term in the Lagrangian with two $A$:s and no other fields. In that case I guess $A+A\to\psi+\bar{\psi}$ could still be possible (through a term in the Lagrangian that contains both $A$:s and $\psi$:s). But is that what is meant by "does not interact with itself"? By the way, as an aside, would that not imply also that $A$ is massless?

Comment: @Oбжорoв I'm really just studying this material at about the level of Griffiths' *Introduction to Elementary Particles*, so I have only a pretty superficial knowledge about how the Feynman rules arise from the Lagrangian.

Comment: $\psi + A \to \psi + A$ is essentially Compton scattering and is a valid process, you might be forgetting about the internal lines of the diagram. $A + A \to \psi + \bar{\psi}$ is a valid diagram if you remember the internal fermion line.

Comment: @Triatticus I am only considering vertices at this point. So when I write $\psi+A\to\psi+A$ I mean a 4-point vertex with $\psi+A$ incoming and $\psi+A$ outgoing.

Comment: I have updated the question with some more thoughts. Am I way off?

Comment: @ummg ah I see, well a vertex alone doesn't typically define a Feynman diagram to begin with, QED has a three particle vertex, but it is an invalid diagram as it doesn't simultaneously satisfy momentum and energy conservation. Maybe you can compare to QED? What you've written so far makes it seem quit similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not well-posed. As @AccidientalFourierTransform says, it all depends what you mean by "does not interact with itself".

If your are only considering a four-point vertex then you need a term containing $\psi, \bar \psi$ and two factors of $A$. But you seem to think that implies that the $A$'s then interact with themselves, so neither process would then be allowed. But if you do not consider this as an interaction of the $A$'s then all combinations are possible, in principle. What is possible in practice depends on many things: the  Lagrangian and its symmetries, whether you want you theory renormalisable etc..

Note that most people would say that a term with only two $A$'s is not an interaction. It defines how the parcel propagates. If you really don't want any terms with two $A$'s then you also don't allow a kinetic term $(\partial A)^2$ and so the $A$ field does not propagate - you can just integrate it out of the path integral.

Do you allow terms with 3 $A$'s?

Comment: I see. I might just have to ask the teacher that suggested the exercise for a clarification in the coming week then. The Lagrangian itself is not given, only the above rules. I just don't know what exactly is meant. What would you say is the standard interpretation of the rule about $A$?

Comment: About terms with 3 $A$'s, I just don't know that either.

Comment: My personal interpretation would be that there are no terms of the form $A^n$ for $n \ge 3$ without any $\psi$s.   A term of the form $\bar \psi \psi A A$ is not a self-interaction for me. But that may be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. And you permit $n=2$ without $\psi$'s because that gives us a mass term, which you do not consider a self-interaction either?

Comment: Again it is a matter of interpretation, but I guess 99% of QFT practitioners would say a mass term is not an interaction. They could however sometimes consider it as an interaction term for educational properties.

Comment: Okay, that is actually quite helpful. I will try this interpretation, at least until I get hold of my teacher. Thank you for doing your best to help, despite me giving you so little to work with!